# "or" in regex, how to find one value or the other

Tags: regex

How would you search for one value or another using regex:

For example:

```
[video= SOMETHING NOT IMPORTANT]
[image= SOMETHING NOT IMPORTANT]
```

So either look for video or image:

```
/\[video|image=([^\]]+)\]/i
```

How would this be done?

Comment: It's often easier to just test against multiple regexes, rather than attempt to combine the two into one pattern.

Comment: @Ether Amen to that. Spent a year trying to create Mothers Of All Regular Expressions, only to realize that things are a lot cleaner if you just match on multiple separate regular expressions.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you'll need to wrap `video|image` in its own subpattern:

```
/\[(?:video|image)=([^\]]+)\]/i
```

The `?:` designates it a non-capture group so your capture/backreference to `([^\]]+)` is untouched.